# About the singularity of the answer to the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the differential equation is given like : $$y'=x \sqrt{y},\quad y(0)=0$$

does this equation has a unique answer?
how can i prove it has or it has not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that there is a trivial solution $y=0$. Then note that there is a nonzero solution given by separation of variables.

Comment: how can i declare it by "existence and singularity of answer" theorem? by continuity of f(x,y) (y'=f(x,y)) and continuity of df/dy ...

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili The "elementary" existence/uniqueness theorem to which you are referring does not apply in this situation, because $f(x,y)=x \sqrt{y}$ is not continuously differentiable with respect to $y$ at $y=0$. The more general existence/uniqueness theorem *also* does not apply in this situation, because $f(x,y)=x \sqrt{y}$ is not Lipschitz continuous at $y=0$. But just because the theorem does not apply does not mean that you will have non-uniqueness. To prove you actually have non-uniqueness you should actually show that there are multiple solutions.

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili For an example of my last point, the existence/uniqueness theorem does not apply to the problem $y'=1+\sqrt{y},y(0)=0$, but this equation has a unique solution regardless.

Comment: thank you for your answer,so if the theorem doesn't apply to a equation,it is possible that there is a unique answer? so it can't be Trusted completely?

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili What the theorem actually *says* is entirely true: if ... then there is a unique solution. It does not say anything about when there is not a unique solution. It *turns out* that a lot of the time, if you break the hypotheses of the existence/uniqueness theorem, you get no solutions or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @MohammadHoseinKhalili (Cont.) But some of the time you get unique solutions anyway. In the example I gave, what's happening is that $y=0$ is a "bad" point, but the $1$ term causes the system to immediately move away from $y=0$. (Indeed, it is easy to see that in my example $y(x) \geq x$.) And for $y>0$ the hypotheses of the theorem actually apply.

Comment: @Ian The solution by separation of variables is $y(x)=\frac{x^4}{16}$. Could you explain how this solution is nonzero? Since it has to satisfy the initial value, it is zero at $x=0$. Thank you.

Comment: @sunny It is zero at that one point but it is not identically zero.

Answer (score -1):

But on can solve $y'/√y = x$ gives $√y=x^2/4+c$ and your get y

Comment: Yes, there is a separable solution. But there is also a stationary solution which will never be identified by separation of variables.